# Why does this triple integral take so long?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

How can I compute this triple integral?

$$I=\underset{V}{\iiint}\frac{(y-1)^3}{x^2+y^2+z^2+1}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\qquad V\begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2\le 4\\x\ge 0\end{cases}$$

I tried this but it has been running for a long time and not return result yet.

```
Integrate[
 Boole[0 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 4]*((y - 1)^3/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1)), {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 
  2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Comment: `NIntegrate` will give a numerical value (-16.755...)

Comment: @mikado that seems right. Someone got -16π/3, why is it hard for Mathematica to get the exact result?

Comment: @hana If I had to guess (and I would be), because "work over this prism and then test membership in a hemisphere" is harder to work with than "work over this sphere and then test membership in a hemisphere", and that the latter likely makes Mathematica more likely to try certain methods (e.g. it knows a sphere is relevant from the domain specification, so will try spherical coordinates etc.).  The domain as a prism doesn't lead it to realize a sphere is present, as that's been coded into the function rather than the domain, so it doesn't try those methods.  But, again: just a guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Integrate[
 Boole[x >= 0]*((y - 1)^3/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1)), {x, y, 
   z} ∈ Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 2]]
```

> `-((16 π)/3)`

Comment: In theory, `Integrate[(y - 1)^3/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1), {x, y, z} ∈ RegionIntersection[HalfSpace[{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}], Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 2]]]` should work just as well, but this version is quite a bit slower than the one in this answer.

Answer (score 12):

Changing to spherical polar coordinates gives an answer that agrees numerically

```
π Integrate[(r^2 Cos[θ] (r Sin[θ] - 1)^3)/(r^2 + 1), {r, 0, 2}, {θ, -π/2, π/2}]
(* -((16 π)/3) *)
```

But doesn't explain why Mathematica struggles with the Cartesian formulation.

Comment: Using the coordinate transformation functionality of *Mathematica*: `ff = Simplify[((y - 1)^3/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1) /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {r, φ, θ}]]) CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", "MappingJacobianDeterminant", {r, φ, θ}]]; Integrate[ff, {r, 0, 2}, {φ, 0, π}, {θ, -π/2, π/2}]`

Comment: Although I did not try, version 13.1 has `IntegrateChangeVariables` as can be checked from this [page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html)